# choosing between two layouts for the same class in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to choose between two different layouts based on a value of a certain parameter and set that layout for my class.Both the layouts are having the same ids of all the views.If we dynamically allocate ids to the views of the two layout wont there be a ambiguity?When i tried practically I am getting a null pointer exception.Is this null pointer because of this ambiguity only??Can anybody please help.

Comment: Post some code and logcat

Comment: even though all views have same ids use different ids for parent layout and then on create set layout based on your value

Comment: @Deepti Maduskar Post Your Code here To make solution

Comment: @Deepti Maduskar post code and error logcat

Comment: Actually the problem was the common views had to be defined after setting the layout.thanks.the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // condition can be from getIntent() or from SharedPreferences or whatever 
    if(condition) {
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    } else {
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2); 
    }

    // If they have the same components, but different layouts only
    // You can use it as usual with findViewById(R.id.view_id);
    Button btnExample = findViewById(R.id.btn_example);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could't understand well what you asked. If i'm correct you asking if you can use the same id for a view on different layouts. 
Yes you can. Unless you try to inflate those two layouts at the same time. Then you will have a problem.

You need to narrow you error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition) {
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    } else {
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2); 
    }
```

When you set different views, it may cause null pointer exception when any of the view is missing between this layouts.

So you should make sure that your **findViewById** returns not null. **OR just add check when you try to use this views in the code.**

**Advanced....**

Anyway if you already know all these things and have enough experience with all these stuffs, Try the belw listed libraries it will help you a lot

1. https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife
2. https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice

You can avoid "***repetitive, cumbersome boilerplate coding parts. Indeed, we should focus on logic, not on meta programming***".

These will help you to avoid all these findViewById...stuffs and you can slim your code...less bugs!